# Can I force automatic wrapping in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, layout

I was wondering if it is possible to force components in BorderLayout to wrap like they do in FlowLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a FlowLayout the components will wrap automatically. The problem is that the height of the panel does not increase automaically, so you may never see the wrapped components. The [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) tries to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

BorderLayout, in principle, have only 5 positions: North, South, East, West and Center. If you want to micro-manage one of those positions, it is best that you put a JPanel there, and tweak its layout (e.g., set it to FlowLayout).

Comment: But I thought FlowLayout is the default layout manager for every JPanel, anyay I tried it and it doesn't wrap, I think because of setting the containing JFrame to BorderLayout, there is some issue with the wrapping.

Comment: Flow layout is the default, *except of the content frame*, that is set to border layout.